# Which usage of the word "Gravity" came first?

Tags: etymology

The link between the two definitions for the word *gravity* (a generally downward acting force, and a sense of danger/seriousness) seems obvious. However, I'm curious as to which usage came first.

Was the word *gravity* first coined to describe Newtonian forces and later used in a figurative sense; or perhaps physicists named the force using a metaphor based on the emotional weight connoted by the term?

Anyone know?

Comment: Doubtless the Latin **gravitas** *weight, heaviness* was also used figuratively of persons, to mean *dignity, presence, influence*. This was all long before Newton "discovered" the force of nature called gravity.

Comment: -1 and voted to close as general reference. This can be answered by a [dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=gravity&allowed_in_frame=0) or simple Google search.

Comment: +1 : this is an interesting question for anyone browsing here

Comment: @cindi: being interesting is not the only requirement for questions.

Comment: I have to agree that this is general reference. Now, if the question were "which meaning came first, *weight* or *seriousness*", *then* it'd be an interesting research project for someone.

Comment: That is exactly the question.

Comment: Welcome back, @JohnFx! I have not seen you here from ages.

Comment: Thanks @kiamlaluno. Kinda got tired of all the bickering and pedantry on the site and gave up on it. Still check in once in a while though.

Comment: @JohnFx I am glad to give you a good news, if you didn't notice: Shinto Sherlock is done! Yippie! By the way, I can know explain you the joke I wrote on meta time ago. `;-)`

Comment: JohnFx, bickering and pedantry aren't necessarily a problem. And they may be useful and fun. What discourages me is how a few people with a few seconds attention can send to the grave hours of useful and interesting work by dozens of others. And feel as if gravitas is on their side. #TheOtherCancelCulture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the OED the earliest meaning was "weighty dignity" in 1509. The "attractive force" meaning is from 1692. The word is borrowed from French *gravité* or Latin *gravitātem* "heavy, weighty".

*grave* meaning "place of burial" has a completely different etymology.

Comment: OED actually has a 1520 and 1533 use, but overall this is right.

Comment: you're right. and there's one from 1509 too.

Comment: Gravity as an "attractive force" simply wasn't normally recognised as a concept at all in antiquity. You're addressing the question of when that concept was recognised enough to be named, but OP is asking which of the two meanings *heavy in mass* and *serious in nature* came first. The concept of *heavy in mass* predates the "attractive force" way of looking at things.

Comment: Is the 1692 from Newton?

Comment: No, it's from *Matter and motion cannot think: or, A confutation of atheism from the faculties of the soul, a sermon, the 2nd of the lecture founded by R. Boyle* by Richard Bentley

Comment: It seems to me that if "gravity" came from "grave" then it would be "graveness", and that "gravity" came from Latin "gravitas" in parallel with "grave" coming from Latin "gravem".

Comment: @phoog you're right, it's not derived from *grave*.